# Schedule SQL Job by Mail

Tags: sql-server, jobs, database-trigger, database-mail

do anybody know how to trigger a SQL job in Microsoft Management Studio when a certain E-Mail will be received?

Thanks in advance

Comment: email is received to whom from whom?

Comment: mail is received in my personal outlook via a distribution list

Comment: from whom? and do you want the job when you opened the email?

Comment: from a normal user within my organization. yes this would already help when i open the mail

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some hints. This may not be the complete answer though. I write here because it will be more clear when I format text.

1. Find a way to trigger the receiving of email
   [Set up the windows to accept running an exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191893/how-to-control-the-rule-actions-to-start-an-application-or-run-a-macro)
2. Write [VBA Script to exec the SQL Job](https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/)

Comment: If you stuck in these , let me know